# stream 0, timescale not set when concat video using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have 2 video which i want to add them together so i make a text file which contains the file names

```
file No-fade_25fps.mp4
file video.mp4
```

then i start using this command

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i ffmpeg-sound.txt -c copy final_output.mp4
```

the problem is i got this from ffmpeg

```
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0561dbc0] stream 0, timescale not set
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0561dbc0] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
Input #0, concat, from 'out.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 464 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 464 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-02-09T10:36:18.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x720 [SAR 72:72 DAR 16:9], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
Output #0, mp4, to 'final_output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.7.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 464 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-02-09T10:36:18.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 05c3e940] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
frame= 8194 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2254kB time=46:35:51.68 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s speed=1.19e+006x
video:2157kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 4.486598%
```

the result give me a video mp4 file with a long duration like 46:33:20 and it not work, and iam sure that both videos have same reslution.
what i tried is to use this command to convert the video

```
ffmpeg -y -i No-fade_25fps.mp4 -r 25 -s 1280x720 -c:v libx264 -b:v 3M -strict -2 -movflags faststart destination.mp4
```

and when i concate them again it worked and give me result mp4 file which have a right duration and worked fine but without a sound, because the first video file i use is muted no sound in it and second one contains a sound.
my question is how to concate those videos togther without this problem also what make the video have the problem of this long duration and when i convert them using the command line it worked?
first video info which is No-fade_25fps.mp4

```
    [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 03e05000] stream 0, timescale not set
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'No-fade_25fps.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4V
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: M4V M4A mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2018-02-09T10:36:18.000000Z
    keywords        : tunepro,orange
    album_artist    : Kiran Khan
    description     : This video is about new tunepro
    artist          : Kiran Khan
    title           : new tunepro
  Duration: 00:00:06.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 497 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 464 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-02-09T10:36:18.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x720 [SAR 72:72 DAR 16:9], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
At least one output file must be specified
```

second video video.mp4

```
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.7.100
  Duration: 00:05:21.28, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 181 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 45 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

what i want is to add any number of videos togthers without a problems like this they all have same reslution and frame per second is there something else need to be checked before i start merge videos?

**Update**
this what i get when i use the command without copy codec

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 058ddb80] stream 0, timescale not set
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 058ddb80] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
Input #0, concat, from 'out.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 464 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 464 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-02-09T10:36:18.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1280x720 [SAR 72:72 DAR 16:9], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 05937d00] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 05937d00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 05937d00] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 05937d00] 264 - core 155 r2901 7d0ff22 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'final_output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.7.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-02-09T10:36:18.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      encoder         : Lavc58.9.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 058ddb80] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filtered=3.41x
More than 1000 frames duplicated
```

and it stop like it's in infinite loop

Comment: easiest is to just make sure all the files you use for concat using -codec copy do share the exact same configuration like audio/video codec, audio track and channel config etc... does it work when you dont have -codec copy in the command? And do you use the latest release 3.4.1?

Comment: Yes i use last version of FFmpeg i tried to add this command and no change, if you want me to add it in a specific way please write me the full command i used this
ffmpeg -f concat -i out.txt -c copy -codec copy final_output.mp4

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, i was asking what happens when you do NOT copy the codec. so just ffmpeg -f concat -i ffmpeg-sound.txt final_output.mp4